# Writing ICS files for multiple clients, including Google

Tags: php, timezone, icalendar

I need to write a script for publishing .ICS files. I've read that it's difficult to do this right, either because some calendar clients are buggy (lots of people claim Google Calendar is extremely buggy especially regarding time zones)  or because developers aren't following the spec properly. I only need to do this for North America but I do have to account for DST (keeping in mind places like Arizona, parts of which observe DST and parts of which don't).

Can anyone answer these questions?

1. When specifying a start and end time
   for an event, should this be
   provided always in the user's local
   time or can I send it as a UTC time
   and leave it to the client to figure
   it out?
2. Do I have to take any extra
   steps to account for DST at the
   user's location?
3. Do I have to take
   any extra steps to account for
   Google?

Any other tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've heard right - it is not easy.  Easy to offer very basic ics support, not that easy to offer complete support to what an ics provider may output; especially wrt recurrences, exceptions, modifications and yes timezones.

I have been working on my ics publisher for a long long time, it is pretty stable now.  I have made some notes along the way.

See http://icalevents.com/category/notes/.  Also the timezone tag on my site you may find helpful.

In particular, if you are getting into recurring events, the " ical cheatsheet" is worth a look.  I rewrote my recurrence engine after working through that.

Google I have not found to be a problem, it is the smaller players, particularly when they start doing slightly non-standard things (Zimbra/Pc based tz's etc).

Although Google can be slow to update (ie someone updates their google calendar, you refetch the ics file (definitely not from your cache) and it does not have the update - can take an hour or so.   This was no good for our school when doing their newsletter - they do a print run too from the website.   SO I have resorted to creating the other side now - our own ics editor in wp.

There are various free ical scripts out there - why roll your own ?   Keen for a challenge?

Comment: Wow. That's perfect. That's what I'm looking for. As for using a prerolled script... to be honest, I've not looked deeply at any and I've been suspicious of the ones I have looked through. This is for a tiny add-on to a friend's (very large and very successful) amateur sports league web site. Her needs are so basic that I thought it would be easier to do from scratch. Then I looked at the RFC. And then I started reading the feedback from other developers. And then I got nervous. Everything except the time zones look like a walk in the park. Any scripts you can recommend?

Comment: Well if you are writing in Php and use the DateTime class (NOT UNIX time), and you keep your thinking cap on about what timezone you are dealing with (the ics files, the events (can be different with in a file)), then timezones are not a problem.  Recur the events within the event timezone and only move to display timezone when ready to output.  If recurrence goes over daylight saving change this is NB - see links on my site. With datetime class Tz is all handled well, you can do date comparison etc.

Comment: I have a free wordpress plugin (amr-ical-events-list) that I am sure is fine with recurrence.  I had intended to port to a standalone version, but not done yet.      There are others (google php ical, ics ) but last I looked they either did not do full recurrence or were trying to cope with timezones using unix time stamp - crazy.   My plugin is a list based (agenda), but would be not that hard to add box calendar.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you very much for your help. If I end up using your code, I'll send you the changes I end up making. Probably they'll be of no use to you, but who knows. I'll be cracking into this in the next month or so.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Times in ICS files can either be floating or fixed.

A floating datetime contains no reference to UTC or a time zone - the time should be the time the ATTENDEE should arrive for the meeting in his/her local timezone. This could result in different attendees having the meeting at different times, so should be used with caution (or never!).

A fixed time is a better way to go. The format changes depending on whether the meeting is taking place in UTC or not.

For UTC meetings, use `Z` to specify UTC:

```
19980119T070000Z
```

Where the meeting is not in UTC, use the TZID format to specify a timezone. The following represents 2am New York time:

```
TZID=America/New_York:19980119T020000
```

Note: the TZID format should not be used for UTC times.

All this is specified in RFC 5545, Sections [3.2.19](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19) and [3.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.4)

The RFC has the following to say about DST - read into it what you will!

> If, based on the definition of the
> referenced time zone, the local time
> described occurs more than once (when
> changing from daylight to standard
> time), the DATE-TIME value refers to
> the first occurrence of the referenced
> time.  Thus, TZID=America/
> New_York:20071104T013000 indicates
> November 4, 2007 at 1:30 A.M. EDT
> (UTC-04:00).  If the local time
> described does not occur (when
> changing from standard to daylight
> time), the DATE-TIME value is
> interpreted using the UTC offset
> before the gap in local times. Thus,
> TZID=America/New_York:20070311T023000
> indicates March 11, 2007 at 3:30 A.M.
> EDT (UTC-04:00), one hour after 1:30
> A.M. EST (UTC-05:00).

Comment: Do you know of any quirks in how ICS is implemented in the major clients? As a web developer, I'm all too familiar with how writing only to the standard will get you in trouble and how the solution is to usually write your code to satisfy both the standard and the major browser quirks. I can't reasonably be expected to handle every known iCalendar client, but I'm hoping there's enough similarity in implementation to build a single file that works the big ones (Outlook, Google Calendar, BlackBerry and iCal for starters).

Comment: +1, after a number of hours of diving into the RFC and Googling like my life depends on it, your post helped me figure my problem out (was using TZID of UTC).