# Is There a Workaround for lack of Olsen TZ TZID Format in ICS File

Tags: outlook, timezone, icalendar

I recently had a problem with an ICS file that I received in email. My copy of Outlook 2010 would not recognize the timezone correctly. Here is the way that the start time of a meeting was represented in the ICS file:

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20110928T183000
```

When Outlook imported this file, it changed the time from 6:30 pm Pacific time to 7:30 pm Pacific time. After some experimentation I was able to get an ICS file that imported correctly in Outlook by changing the time zone format:

```
DTSTART;TZID="Pacific Time":20110928T183000
```

After some further research I found that the [ICS file specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) leaves the question of time zone identification open, but suggests using [the Olsen TZ database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). It appears that the Microsoft Outlook team has chosen to ignore this suggestion.

Given that Outlook is a fairly popular calendar client, is there a reliable way to format ICS time zones for Outlook that is still compatible with other clients? My biggest concern about this issue is the silent error during the Outlook import. Users could easily show up for a meeting at the wrong time, since Outlook gives no warning that it's confused about the time zone. Should we simply direct Outlook users to a different file format?

*Note: I know that this question is similar to [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763503/writing-ics-files-for-multiple-clients-including-google), but the references on that post appear to have expired, and I'm wondering if there are any better solutions out there.*

Comment: The link in the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763503/writing-ics-files-for-multiple-clients-including-google is now http://icalevents.com/category/notes/. And the most interesting post related to your question seems to be http://icalevents.com/2613-what-every-developer-ought-to-know-about-timezones-wrt-calendar-files/ - but it only talks about parsing ics files (and different tz ids), not what to do when sending them out to multiple clients. Hrmmpf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hard to judge without the full iCalendar file but did you define/do you have a `VTIMEZONE` component in your calendar file which defines what America/Los_Angeles should be?

Something like:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Comment: Egads! That worked! Note: be sure to get the VTIMEZONE definition in before the closing END:VCALENDAR tag. Thanks @oberron!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the timezone definition to the ics file, it would be better to mention the event start/end times in UTC itself. 
And then, the consumer of the ICS file - outlook in your case - should be able to do the timezone conversion from UTC(from ics file) to the preferred timezone setting of the end user, just before rendering the meeting event on their calendars.

**Pros:**
This way you dont have to take care of adding the correct timezone offsets (VTIMEZONE component) yourself.
Plus, the ics file is much smaller, cleaner, easy to read.

**References:**
Even google seems to be handling timezones in ics this way itself -  [Google timezone handling](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2367918?hl=en)

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Cons**: Doesn't handle daylight savings changes correctly for the target time zone.

Comment: Timezones are actually hugely complex political mess with lots of historical mishaps. Adding a short description for the _current year_ doesn't really cut it. If you truly must have _some_ support for Outlook, I guess describing the current year is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the questioner lives in Los Angeles and uses OUTLOOK2010.
And `20110928T183000` Start time is based on PDT
If you want to make meeting successful, You add Meeting appointment item, contact, and google map URL Address phone open time in description.
Of course, meeting item should add  Organizer and Attendee, but it is so hard to set. 
And about 75 octet carriage return and inserting space is difficult. So only set organizer and attendee write in description.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20110928T183000
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20110928T203000
LOCATION:meeting room in Los Angeles
Description:maps link \nhttp... \n phone \n open at 10:00:AM(PDT)
UID:ev1
ORGANIZER;CN="ThisMeeting Orginizer":mailto:meetingorginer@example.com
Contact:meetingsupport@example.com
DTSTAMP:20111001T105433Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```