# ics file issues

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I have a sample ics file like this

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20120328T073000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20120328T093000
SUMMARY:Test EVENT
LOCATION:Test Location
DESCRIPTION:Test Description
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It works fine when importing to Google Calendar but in Outlook the times are off by 2 hours. What can be the issue?

Regards,
Neel

Comment: Outlook's configured your calendar for a different timezone, probably.

Comment: Could be an issue with how Outlook interpret the timezone, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436629/is-there-a-workaround-for-lack-of-olsen-tz-tzid-format-in-ics-file

Answer (score 1):

to secure behaviour compatible with your expectation you need to define your tzid in a "VTIMEZONE" calendar component.

see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545
§3.2.19.  Time Zone Identifier
This property parameter specifies a text value that uniquely identifies the "`VTIMEZONE`" calendar component

and

```
3.6.5.  Time Zone Component
Component Name:  VTIMEZONE
Purpose:  Provide a grouping of component properties that defines a time zone.
```

something like this added on top of your calendar (before vevent) would do the job:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
LAST-MODIFIED:19870101T000000Z
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19971026T020000
RDATE:19971026T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19971026T020000
RDATE:19970406T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Comment: Dear oberron,my understandingis that the VTIMEZONE defines a timezone in case that timezone definition is different from the default on the receiving system (eg one more out of date wrt daylight saving changes etc) .  Calendar applications should be able to handle dates adequately if a standard timezone code is used in the date as per above.

Comment: I agree it would be common sense but given that RFC5545 states 3.2.19 TZID "Note: This document does not define a naming convention for time zone identifiers.  Implementers may want to use the naming         conventions defined in existing time zone specifications such as the public-domain TZ database [TZDB].  The specification of globally unique time zone identifiers [...]" one might be taking the risky road to assume all developpers are doing things which would be expected from common sense (or maybe there common sense has been overruled by pointy-haired bosses :) )