# Multiple timezones for an Outlook ICS?

Tags: php, datetime, outlook, icalendar

*I have already visited this question [Is There a Workaround for lack of Olsen TZ TZID Format in ICS File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436629/is-there-a-workaround-for-lack-of-olsen-tz-tzid-format-in-ics-file)*

I was able to understand why Outlook messes up with the times of two events in same timezone but in daylight save mode eg:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID: // Some staff
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Adak Events
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ev1
DTSTART;TZID=America/Adak:20140619T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/Adak:20140619T130000
DTSTAMP:20150409T105433Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
SUMMARY:Adak Event
LOCATION:Adak
DESCRIPTION: Summer
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ev2
DTSTART;TZID=America/Adak:20141219T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/Adak:20141219T130000
DTSTAMP:20150409T105433Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
SUMMARY:Adak Event
LOCATION:Adak
DESCRIPTION: Winter
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

But my real question what happens when I want to have multiple events in multiple timezones? I have seen that the solution to specify a timezone is:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20140330T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20141026T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

But when I have multiple timezones in a single ICS? How can I handle such a thing for Outlook?

*PS: In other mail apps TZID did the job so far*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define multiple time zones. And dates in the VEVENT part can refer to these multiple time zones.

Answer (score 0):

First,  defining America/Adak Time Zone by olson database
And 2 events are, so defining 2 Items
`x-WR-CALNAME:icsfilename:Solstice`
`x-WR-CALDESC:Added with ics file`
but 2014 is too old so I change year setting 2014 > 2019 
Summer and Winter solitude

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
RODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 19.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
x-WR-CALNAME:icsfilename
x-WR-CALDESC:Added ics file :icsfilename.ics
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Adak
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Adak
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Adak
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-1000
TZOFFSETTO:-0900
TZNAME:HST
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0900
TZOFFSETTO:-1000
TZNAME:HDT
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ev1
DTSTART;TZID=America/Adak:20190621T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/Adak:20190621T130000
DTSTAMP:20150409T105433Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
SUMMARY:Adak Event
LOCATION:Adak
DESCRIPTION:Summer
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:ev2
DTSTART;TZID=America/Adak:20191221T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/Adak:20191221T130000
DTSTAMP:20150409T105433Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
SUMMARY:Adak Event
LOCATION:Adak
DESCRIPTION:Winter
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```